# How do I INSERT INTO from one mysql table into another table and set the value of one column?

Tags: mysql, insert

I need to insert data from table1 into table2. However, I would like to set the myYear column in table2 to 2010. But, there isn't a myYear Column in table1.

So, my basic insert looks like:

```
INSERT INTO  `table2` ( place, event ) 
SELECT place, event
FROM table1
```

Roughly, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` ( place, event, SET myYear='2010' )
...
```

Is there a way to set the column value in the insert statement?

Comment: +1 for showing attempted answer so we could see exactly what you were trying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (place, event, myYear) 
SELECT place, event, '2010'
FROM   table1;
```

Basic test case:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a int, b int);
CREATE TABLE t2 (c int);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

INSERT INTO t1 SELECT c, 100 FROM t2;

SELECT * FROM t1;

+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |  100 | 
|    2 |  100 | 
|    3 |  100 | 
|    4 |  100 | 
|    5 |  100 | 
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (place, event, myYear)
SELECT place, event, 2010
FROM table1
```

*Edit: bah, didn't get the answer posted notification :P*

Comment: Hi Dusty, Thanks for the correct answer. Daniel beat you by 3 minutes ;)

Thanks for the help.
-Laxmidi